# RandomAccessFile Java - complexity

Tags: java, io, complexity-theory

i am using RandomAccessFile in a Java program on Linux that deals with a huge amount of data.

so what i am doing is i keep many files, each file contains different information.

when i preform the action

```
int x=???//some large number
RandomAccessFile rand = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt","r");
rand.seek(x); //the file contains more than x bytes
 byte b = rand.readByte();
```

what is the complexity of the program?
does the program preform 2 actions in the last 2 lines?
one for seeking to the xth byte and one for reading the byte? - in other words the whole file is in one consecutive location on the disk(like an array)?
or does it preform x actions for the seek and one for the reading?

thank you

Matt

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but I assume something like this could be implementation/platform specific, so it might help to state which OS and JVM you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seek just positions the internal pointer, it doesn't read anything from the disk.

Comment: thank you for the reply.
but my question is when seek positions the internal pointer, does it began from the beginning of the file and move the pointer byte after byte (x times) or does it straight position the pointer on the xth byte

Comment: No. In simple terms, it does something like: pointer = x; And when you read, it read the sector from the hdd (512 bytes) containing your byte.

Answer (score 4):

Seek is O(1) or close to that. It doesn't have to run through the file to your position.

Answer (score 0):

`seek` is almost constant. Positioning the pointer to the `x`th byte is usually O(1) like an array lookup, but sometimes files are fragmented on disk, it can take #-of-fragments steps to find the `x`th byte.